# How to get information about all WooCommerce products without choosing a category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I made a category selection section that can be used to specify the woocommerce product category and then display the products of that category.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => intval($_POST['category']),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    ));
$id_posts = get_posts($args);
```

But I want to display all products when a category is not selected.How do I value 'terms' to achieve my goal?

Comment: You should not add the whole `tax_query` to the arguments in the first place then. (Resp. the other way around, because that is easier - prepare your $args without it, and then afterwards _add_ it - `$args['tax_query'] = ...`, if you have a category value in your POST data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a function that checks all your categories in order and then gives you the ID of the categories.
Now you can put these ideas in terms.

```php
function get_all_ID_category()
{
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => "product_cat",
        'number' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );

    $product_categories = get_terms($args);
    $product_cat = [];

    foreach ($product_categories as $pc) {
        $int_pc = $pc->term_id;
        $product_cat[] = $int_pc;
    }

    return $product_cat;
}

function get_all_posts_category()
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'fields' => 'ids',
                'terms' => get_all_ID_category(),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    );

    return get_posts($args);
}
```